# How can emitter bias amplify since the emitter current is fixed?

Tags: bjt, common-emitter

[image]

My textbook says \$I_E\$ is fixed at \$V_{BB}/R_E\$ no matter what the current gain of the transistor is. This is confusing me a lot. Since the emitter current cannot change, how can this ciruit amplify anything ?

---

When I feed in some signal \$v_b(t)\$ to the base, I think it simply appears across the \$R_E\$, emitter current would then be \$(V_{BB} + v_b(t))/R_E\$. See no amplification ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of small-signal analysis? What's the difference between \$I_E\$ and \$i_e\$? I'm assuming a common-emitter configuration.

Comment: Where do you apply your small signal input? Are you running this in common base or common emitter? If we don't know this, we can say nothing about amplification.

Comment: Hey not yet, I'm studying biasing at the moment. I think small letters are ac and caps dc ?

Comment: @Bart I don't really know, I got stuck at this while reading about biasing.  Is it okay if we assume the signal input is in series with \$V_{BB}\$ ?

Comment: In series, or superposed, which happens when you bias with a resistor instead of a low impedance voltage source. What matters is, that the base voltage has an AC component, which is your small signal. With regard to the small signal then, you will have voltage and current amplification at the collector, but only current amplification at the emitter.

Comment: Yeah doesn't that ac component drop across \$R_E\$ and the output would simply be a dc shifted one w/o any amplification to the signal right ? I feel I grossly misunderstood something :[

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301617/bjt-input-ac-signal-amplitude/301642#301642

Comment: @G36 Exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you for the detailed graphs, looks I'm getting hang of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input signal is at the base and you expect voltage amplification then your output must be at the collector however, with only 1 kohm in the collector and 22 kohm in the emitter, amplification will be a lot less than 1. But, if those two resistors were swapped around, you would find that the voltage amplification is approximately 22 i.e. the ratio of collector resistor to emitter resistor (which is a fairly good shorthand approximation to the circuit voltage gain).

Also, remember that in this configuration the gain is inverting.

Comment: sorry I'm still not getting it :( when I_E is fixed, I_C is also fixed. In emitter bias, I_E doesn't change much with the input signal v_b(t) right ?

Comment: \$V_{BB}/R_E\$ or \$(V_{BB} + v_b(t))/R_E\$, the difference is   just \$v_b(t)/R_E\$ hmm

Comment: I think I see why R_C/R_E gives the voltage gain. For ac, emitter voltage will be same as the input voltage. But this small change in emitter voltage is causing large ac drop across the collector resistor. Thus amplification XD Thank you :)

Comment: @andy - Minor comment regarding DC bias conditions.  I think the original circuit has 2.2k in the emitter and 1k in the collector.  The DC conditions would be ok with about 13v at the collector and a gain of 2.2. if you swap the resistors the transistor will be saturated.

Comment: @KevinWhite yes, you may be right about the resistor and of course, the dc bias at the base has to be such that the quiescent voltage resulting at the collector is somewhere about half Vcc.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you already know what biasing is and how that amplifier works but let me help you to look at them from a different aspect.

As you might know, for a transistor to work properly, a biasing voltage (DC) should be applied to the base so that \$V_{BE}\$ can be 0.6VDC and a non-zero collector current, \$I_C\$, can flow. And if there's no AC signal at the input, the circuit will stay at that situation which we call **quiescent**.

In your circuit, under quiescent, base current is constant, because base voltage (\$V_{BB}\$) is constant. And collector (and thus, emitter) current is constant, because \$V_{BE}\$ is constant.

Now, if you apply a small AC voltage, there will be a small variation on base voltage *(Remember, base voltage was constant under quiescent)*, \$\Delta v_b\$. This will cause a small variation on base current, \$\Delta i_b\$. And, finally, this will lead a large current variation on collector current, \$\Delta i_c = \beta \cdot \Delta i_b\$ . If you put a resistor, you'll turn this current variation into a voltage variation. That's what we call **amplification**.

Comment: Awesome! I think I see now what voltage and current amplification is. If I understand correctly, current gain depends on the transistor. But voltage gain can be tweaked by increasing the value of collector resistance. Since current is fixed, I can choose the collector resistor as high as that allows V_CC - V_E drop right ?
 Thank you :)

Comment: Exactly. But voltage gain can be transistor-dependent. And generally we dont want the voltage gain to be transistor (in other words, \$\beta\$)-dependent, because \$\beta\$ varies from transistor to transistor even for the same brand/model. That's why we put an emitter resistor to neglect (or minimize) the effect of transistor's internal parameters.

Comment: If you run the Re to zero, using just the internal gm (dIc/dVe) to cause variations in Icollector, you'll find the maximum gain a single bipolar transistor can achieve is VDD/0.026 volts.