# What is the gain of this n-MOS transistor?

Tags: mosfet

I am wondering how to compute the AC gain of this transistor. So far, I know I have to apply the small signal mode, but **I am not sure what \$V_{gs}(AC)\$ is**. If someone could just clear that up from me, I would greatly appreciate it.

This is not homework, just self-study.

[image]

Comment: Is the - terminal of the 8 V supply meant to be connected to ground or not?

Comment: Yes, the little semicircle must have appeared as I was designing the circuit with CircuitLab.

Comment: AC gain is a voltage gain for AC signals. And the gain is gm*RD. In your case, Vgs = V2 because the gate current is 0A https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301617/bjt-input-ac-signal-amplitude/301642#301642

Comment: That was my thought. But, wouldn't R1 also be included in Vgs, since it is after the voltage source V2, and not directly at the gate?

Comment: The voltage across R1 is I*R1 and since I = 0A. No voltage drop across R1.

Comment: So then, Vgs = V2 for sure?

Comment: For AC signal only V2 = Vgs.  But for DC Vgs = V3 * R3/(R2 + R3)

Answer (score 0):

For small-signal AC purposes R2 and R3 are in parallel to ground, so you have 50 ohms to ground in series with 100 ohms (R1) in series with V2.  So your input to your small signal gate model is your source in series with 150 ohms.  From there, you can figure out what Vgs is based on which small-signal model you are using.

Comment: I am using the following signal model: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw4G2.png . I have been able to set all the resistors and voltage source as you said, but now I don't know how to compute \$V_{gs}\$

Comment: That model has no input capacitance, so no current flows in the gate, and Vgs is just V2.  Gate capacitance wouldn't make a big difference for low frequencies, but could have an effect at high frequency.