# CE/CB BJT Amplifier(s) + Load Lines!

Tags: transistors, bjt

This diagram from a lab assignment is not making sense to me.

[image: Diagram]

I don't understand what \$I_{C_\max}\cdot R_e\$ is and why it appears on this diagram. Even if it should be on the diagram, why is it only \$R_e \$ and not \$R_{\text{DC}}\$? Shouldn't \$V_{CE_\min}\$ be from \$0\mathrm{ V}\$ to \$\sim0.3\mathrm{ V}\$?

When calculating \$R_e\$ and \$R_c\$, this equation is used:

[image: Equation]

I've tried leaving the term I don't understand out (probably a bad idea), which causes either \$R_c\$ or \$R_e\$ to be negative and I have tried calling it \$I_{C_\max}\cdot R_{DC}\$, which results in two negative resistances...

Side question:

[image: CB Diagram]

For a common base amplifier, would \$R_{\text{AC}}\$ include \$R_s\$ (the signal resistance)? Thus should it be \$R_C\parallel R_L + R_e\parallel R_s\$?

Comment: Look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301617/bjt-input-ac-signal-amplitude/301642#301642 and notice how the voltage across RE resistor change with an input signal.

Comment: You are thinking of Vce(sat ) instead of Vce(min for linear operation.  THis depends on harmonic distortion spec or variation of sine asymmetry which can easily be 10% when Vce< 1V and at high current <2V .  I would choose a number in that preferred linear  range depending on Ic/Ic max

Comment: Tyler, Have you found an answer to your questions, yet? (The given equations, by the way, aren't correct. So I'd like to know exactly where this came from. For example, the computation for \$V_\text{CC}\$ is incorrect and so therefore is everything that flows from it. [That is, unless I can't follow the context of this -- which is why I'd like to know where it comes from.])