Why is the gain of a BJT common emitter amplifier roughly given by this?
This video says the gain of a BJT common emitter amplifier (as in the first picture below) roughly given by \$gain =- R3/R4\$. Why is it \$R3/R4\$?

Isn't the small signal equivalent circuit like this map below (I drew in powerpoint)? By this equivalent circuit, we should have \$gain = - \beta \frac{R_3||R_L}{r}\$, which is not the same as said in the video. Considering the \$\beta\$, \$r\$ here are intrinsic to the bjt and \$R_3||R_L\$ has nothing to do with \$R_4\$, the gain shouldn't even relate to \$R_4\$. I'm confused.


Take a look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301617/bjt-input-ac-signal-amplitude/301642#301642  Any additional questions?

The voltage gain will be lower than \$- \beta \frac{R_3||R_L}{r}\$
Because now the voltage across \$r\$ is no longer equal to \$V_{IN}\$.
We have a voltage divider.
Thus, the voltage across \$r\$ will be lower by the factor of:
\$ \frac{r}{r + (\beta + 1)R_4}\$
Therefore the overall gain will be
$$A_V = \frac{r}{r + (\beta + 1)R_4} * \beta \frac{R_3||R_L}{r} =\beta \: \frac{R_3||R_L}{r + (\beta + 1)R_4} = $$
$$ = \frac{R_3||R_L}{R_4 + \frac{r}{\beta +1}} * \frac{\beta}{\beta + 1} = \frac{R_3||R_L}{R_4 + r_e} * \frac{\beta}{\beta + 1} $$
And if \$ R_4 >> \frac{r}{\beta + 1}\$ (what is usually the case) we can ignore \$r\$ influance on the voltage gain.
And the voltage gain becomes equal to:
$$ AV \approx \frac{R_3||R_L}{R_4}$$

Because...

Emitter and collector currents are assumed to be the same value AND,
The AC emitter voltage has a value close to the AC base value

So, if the emitter AC voltage is the base AC voltage and the collector/emitter AC signal current flows through both resistors (which it largely does) then gain = R3/R4 (actually -R3/R4 because the common emitter inverts the input signal).
Andy

You mean the video assumes that $v_{in}$ all falls on $R_4$?

I didn't need to watch the video; the relationship is cut-in-stone nearly as much as the ten commandments @IcenFire
